# Passing a list of parameters into a Python function

Tags: python, list, parameters, tuples, variadic-functions

How would I pass an unknown number of parameters into a function? I have a function defined in the following way

```
def func(x, *p):
    # do something with variable number of parameters (*p)
    pass
```

I'm trying to pass in a list of values to use as parameters. I tried using a list and a tuple but the function always returns zero. Has anyone got any advice?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
some_list = ["some", "values", "in", "a", "list", ]
func(*some_list)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
func("some", "values", "in", "a", "list")
```

The fixed `x` param might warrant a thought:

```
func(5, *some_list)
```

... is equivalent to:

```
func(5, "some", "values", "in", "a", "list")
```

If you don't specify value for `x` (`5` in the example above), then first value of `some_list` will get passed to `func` as `x` param.

Comment: Hy, do you have an idea of how to do something like:
func(first="some", name="values", third="in", another="a", last="list")
from a list  some_list = [(attr_1, value1), (attr2, value2), ...] or a dict ?

Answer (score 8):

Pass the values as comma separated values

```
>>> def func(x, *p):           # p is stored as tuple
...     print "x =",x
...     for i in p:
...         print i
...     return p
... 
>>> print func(1,2,3,4)        # x value 1, p takes the rest
x = 1
2
3
4
(2,3,4)                        # returns p as a tuple
```

You can learn more by reading the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists)